# Setting the Aquamacs font to match the font in the terminal

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, aquamacs

I'm using aquamacs on OSX (snow leopard) and I'm trying to configure the font to look exactly the way it looks when I run emacs in the terminal.
Yet, when I set the exact same font (Monaco 13pt), the text looks blurry in the aquamacs window while it looks sharp and pristine in the emacs in the terminal window.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences, then click on Aquqmqcs (bottom of the dialog), then you'll find "Ns Antialias Text" somewhere around the middle of the window. Click on "Toggle" to set it to "nil".

Comment: For me (not an Aquamacs user) it's toward the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the option for Anti-Aliasing and disable it. Some editors have it, some don't. Does AquaMacs have this option? (The screenshot below is for example for Terminal.app)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Customize option `ns-antialias-text' to nil.

Comment: Could you explain where this option is?